# Quarkus: Unable to create custom annotation for microprofile APIResponses - Error - '@APIResponses' not applicable to annotation type

Tags: swagger, openapi, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

Quarkus with microprofile openapi and swagger.
We are trying to create custom annotation for @APIResponses.
Is this possible in quarkus?

```
`org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.APIResponses;`
`package org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.*;`

`@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})`
`@Inherited`
`@Documented`
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`
`@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`
`@ApplicationScoped`
`@APIResponses(value = {`
`@APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = ".."),`
`@APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "..") ,`
`@APIResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "..") }`
`)`
`public @interface customApiResponse {`
`}`
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of being possible in Quarkus but more possible with MicroProfile OpenAPI.

The `ApiResponses` annotation has a target defined to `@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })` so you cannot use it on a type, only on methods.

Probably a good idea to raise the issue to the MicroProfile OpenAPI project explaining what you want to do and why and see if something should be changed. Then it will naturally end up in Quarkus.

Comment: Yes. due to target as method we are not able apply it to annotation type. @Target({ ElementType.METHOD })

Comment: We are trying refactor our resources code so that we can have custom annotation for redundant @APIResponses(). This will make our code cleaner with just one custom annotation on top of resource/controller methods

Comment: @vaibhavSO, did you find a way to solve it? I would like to do the same optimization with my code